# Black Jack - adding a card to hand

Tags: c

I'm not really sure how to go about even solving. So I am programming blackJack and I have my function declarations (as shown) as such, and for my add_card_to_hand function, I don't know what to do. I have 2 arguments, a hand that I have passed by reference since I'm gonna be changing its internal values and a card; the card that I am adding to the hand. So how do I actually add the card to the hand? I also don't know the type, I just put hand_t, it might be void.

```
typedef enum { HEARTS, DIAMONDS, SPADES, CLUBS } suit_t;
typedef enum { ACE = 1, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT,   NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING } value_t;

typedef struct {
    suit_t suit;
    value_t value;
} card_t;

typedef struct {
    card_t* deck;
    int num_decks;
    int nextcard;
} shoe_t;

typedef struct {
    card_t playercards[21];
    int num_cards_in_array;
} hand_t;


hand_t add_card_to_hand(hand_t* hand, card_t card) {



  }
```

Comment: You need to first learn the game of blackjack. There's no way a hand can hold 21 cards. Even the lowest cards (aces counted as 1) would max out far below that - A+A+A+A+2+2+2+2+3+3+3 would equal 21 (a win), and any single card higher than a 3 anywhere would go over 21. That's a max of 11 cards. What would happen if you're actually playing cards, and you're dealt a card? You add it to your hand. Do the same in your code.

Comment: @user3386109: Um... `num_cards_in_array`?

Comment: `hand->playercards[hand->num_cards_in_array++]=card` ??

Comment: @KenWhite Oops. But right back at you... `num_decks`. If the shoe contains at least six decks, you could have a hand of 21 cards, all aces.

Comment: @user3386109  And that should be worth big money.  ;)

Comment: @user3386109: No, you can't, unless you're lucky enough to be dealt 21 aces in a row (at which point they should be firing the dealer for cheating and arresting you for a crime). At most places, if you receive over a set number of cards (usually 5 or 7) without going over 21, you automatically win anyway.

Comment: @KenWhite LOL, not my fault if I'm really lucky. But seriously, the OP correctly identified the worst case, and sized the array appropriately.

Comment: @user3386109: See my last comment, especially the last sentence. Also, even if you were getting straight ace deals, you'd win before 21 cards, as you'd count one of the aces as 11 instead of 1, which would be a max of 12 cards (1 @ 11 + 10 @ 1 = 21) - there would never be a reason to risk going beyond that point..

Comment: @KenWhite Yeah, you edited while I was responding. The OP *could* implement such a rule I suppose, and then change the array size accordingly.

Comment: @user3386109: Yep. Just did it again, I think. Read my last comment again.

Comment: And be dumb enough to hit on 11 aces.  LOL!  But yeah, I tend to agree with @user3386109.  The OP identified an upper bound for the array.

Comment: So I would return the card? @MFisherKDX & I can chose how many decks I want to play with so I could chose 1000 decks so I could have 21 aces.

Comment: @StacyWillis The line of code that MFisherKDX posted will make a copy of the card information and put it into the `playercards` array. The original card stays in the `shoe`. At the end of the hand, all you need to do is set `num_cards_in_array` back to zero to clear the player's hand.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MAX_HAND_CARDS 21

typedef struct {
    card_t playercards[MAX_HAND_CARDS];
    int num_cards_in_array;
} hand_t;


int add_card_to_hand(hand_t* hand, const card_t card) {

    if (hand->num_cards_in_array >= MAX_HAND_CARDS) {
        return -1;
    }   

    hand->playercards[hand->num_cards_in_array] = card;
    hand->num_cards_in_array++;

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    hand_t *hand = calloc(1, sizeof(hand_t));
    card_t *card = malloc(sizeof(card_t));
    card->suit = HEARTS;
    card->value = ACE;

    if (add_card_to_hand(hand, *card)) {
        printf("failed to add Card\n");
    } else {
        printf("card added\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

don't know much about black jack, but this should work.